# pseudo class hover in CSS

Tags: html, css

Been trying to learn about CSS and the use of hover psuedo classes over elements.  Whenever I select a tab in the navigation bar, the background colour changes colour ( which is what I want).  However, when I move off the anchor text the text changes back to white.

Ideally what I'm wanting is for the navigation tab to turn the background colour white, and the text black together simultaneously when the mouse hovers over.  Here's the code:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="title">
                <h1>Record Store</h1>

        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Vinyl Stock</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Online Offers</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Collectors News</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and CSS code:

```
* {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}
#container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-height: 600px;
    z-index: -9;
}
#title {
    margin:auto;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    height: 30%;
}
#navigation {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
.navbar {
}
.navbar ul {
}
.navbar li {
    font: bold 12px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;
    height: auto;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    float:left;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 1% 0px;
}
.navbar a {
    border-right: 1px solid #1F5065;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar a:hover {
    color: black;
}
.navbar li:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Can someone have a look and point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to be more conscientious about defining your selectors.  You're doing one thing when somebody hover over an `li` and something else when they hover over the `a`.  What you want is to change both elements when hovering over a common element.

To solve the problem, remove:

```
.navbar a:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

And replace it with:

```
.navbar li:hover a {
    color: black;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W5PWG/)

The first selector says "Get all `a:hover`'s that are children in `.navbar`,"  The second selector says "Get all `a`'s that are children in `li:hover`'s that are children of `.navbar.`"

Comment: So does this read along the lines of: if hover over the .navbar <li> element, change the <a> text colour to black?

Comment: Funny, I added that to my answer while you were probably writing your comment.  It reads more like "Get all a's in li:hover in .navbar; apply color: black;"